# ERROR: '~mosquitto-dev' user or team does not exist

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, apt, mosquitto

I am trying to add mosquitto ppa repository in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and I am getting below error:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~mosquitto-dev/ubuntu/mosquitto-ppa'.
ERROR: '~mosquitto-dev' user or team does not exist.
```

I am able to use apt-get install mosquitto but I want to install a latest version of mosquitto hence adding the repository.

I am able to connect to internet and installed mosquitto using apt-get install and also able to wget google.com but not able to ping google.com.

I also tried -E option in add repository command but still having same issue.

Any suggestion to fix the error for adding PPA repository?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a Ubuntu admin task not really a Software Development problem. I suggest you ask on https://askubuntu.com